# Mark previous notification from list as read?

Tags: command-line, notification, dbus, notify-osd, zenity

I am running a service that will notify as frequently as every 5 minutes on condition.

These notifications are important, but in addition to every popup, I only ever want to see the most recent notification in the notifications list, so I have attempted to replace the previous notification using a unique identifier for notify-send and zenity.

The best I have been able to do is to is replace the current *popup* notification, if it has not already timed out, but they still stack in the notification list.

[image]

Alternatively I can make it so the notification only appears as a popup and never appears in the list, but I want this functionality for when I return after being away.

Is it possible for the new notification to delete or replace the previous notification in the list?

```
notify () {
  local message="$1"
  local id="999123"

  # Check if a notification exists to cancel:
  if notify-send --query "$id"; then
    notify-send --cancel "$id"
  fi

  notify-send "$id" "$message"
  #notify-send --hint int:transient:1 "$message"
}

message="New notification"
notify "$message"
```

I dabbled with dbus briefly but have not been able to yet generate a basic test notifcation for some reason.

```
dbus-send --dest=org.freedesktop.ExampleName               \
            /org/freedesktop/sample/object/name              \
            org.freedesktop.ExampleInterface.ExampleMethod   \
            int32:47 string:'hello world' double:65.32       \
            array:string:"1st item","next item","last item"  \
            dict:string:int32:"one",1,"two",2,"three",3      \
            variant:int32:-8                                 \
            objpath:/org/freedesktop/sample/object/name
```

*Ubuntu 22.04 & 23.10.*